# Mysql stops working after build in Electron

Tags: mysql, node.js, electron, electron-builder

I have a Electron application that on its initial window, has a simple login form.
When I use it pre-builiding, it works perfectly, with local and remote databases.
After I build it using electron-builder, it simply fails to connect to any databases, with no error messages shown, it acts as if it can't reach the database.
I'm using mysql and its library from nodejs.